# Correctness of algorithm for computing diameter of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

I am a TA for an introductory CS course, and one question given to students was how to use BFS to determine the diameter of a unweighted, undirected graph. The students were told they wouldn't be graded for efficiency, so the expected answer was a brute force algorithm where they ran BFS from every node to every other node and returned the maximum distance from these BFS runs. The students were provided with a BFS method they could reference in their pseudocode which took as an input a node and returned two mappings: one from each node in the graph to its distance from the start node (called distmap), and one from each node to its 'parent node' along the shortest path from the input node (called parentmap).

One student wrote the following algorithm:

> 1. Choose an arbitrary node from the graph and run BFS from it.
> 2. Create a set Temp of all the nodes that are not values in parentmap (i.e. the leaves of the BFS tree)
> 3. Initialize max_dist to 0
> 4. For each node n in Temp:
>
>    1. Run BFS from n
>    2. For each value d in distmap:
>
>       1. IF d > max_dist THEN set max_dist equal to d
> 5. RETURN max_dist

I believe this answer is correct, but I am unable to prove it. Can someone prove why it works or provide a counterexample?

Comment: Is the graph in question directed, or undirected, is it weighted, or unweighted, and is it a tree?

Comment: @JaysonBoubin It is undirected, unweighted, and not necessarily a tree, though it can be

Comment: There's a massive difference between nodes that don't lie on **any** shortest path (what's stated in brackets of step 2), and nodes that don't lie on **one** shortest path (what step 2 actually seems to do). What is a "parent node" in an undirected graph?

Comment: What does "not lying on any shortest path" mean? A node at least lies on the shortest path to itself.

Comment: Does it actually mean leaves in a bfs tree?

Comment: I read it as: Temp is the set of all nodes with maximum distance from the arbitrary node of step 1. Is that correct?

Comment: It's probably best to just post an example (here and for algorithm questions in general) of what the method returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a slightly simpler counter-example:

[image]

It is quite clear that the maximum distance in this graph is between the green nodes (4), but if you start your BFS from the red node, `Temp` will consist of the two blue nodes only, which gives an incorrect "diameter" of 3.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that not being in a parentmap means being a leaf in a BFS tree, the algorithm is wrong.

Let the graph have 10 vertices and the following undirected edges:

```
0 1
0 4
1 2
1 3
2 3
2 6
2 7
3 8
4 5
4 6
5 9
6 7
6 8
7 8
7 9
```

One of the valid BFS trees (with root `0`) is:

```
0 1
1 2
1 3
2 7
3 8
0 4
4 6
4 5
5 9
```

The leaves are `6, 7, 8, 9`, so this solution returns 3.
That's wrong. The answer is `4` (it's the distance between `3` and `5`).

Taking all furthest nodes doesn't work either for this test.

Instead of asking someone to find a counterexample, you can do it by generating millions of small random test cases and checking if the solution produces a correct answer. Here's the code I used to generate this case (it doesn't look very good, but it does the job):

```
pair<vector<int>, set<int>> bfs(int st, const vector<vector<int>>& g) {
    int n = g.size();
    vector<int> d(n, n);
    d[st] = 0;
    queue<int> q;
    q.push(st);
    set<int> parents;
    while (!q.empty()) {
        int v = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for (int to : g[v])
            if (d[to] > d[v] + 1) {
                d[to] = d[v] + 1;
                q.push(to);
                parents.insert(v);
            }
    }
    return {d, parents};
}

int get_max_dist(const vector<vector<int>>& g) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)g.size(); i++) {
        auto cur = bfs(i, g).first;
        for (int x : cur)
            cerr << x << " ";
        cerr << endl;
        res = max(res, *max_element(cur.begin(), cur.end()));
    }
    cerr << endl;
    return res;
}

int get_max_dist_weird(const vector<vector<int>>& g) {
    auto p = bfs(0, g);
    vector<int> cand;
    int n = g.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (!p.second.count(i))
            cand.push_back(i);
    int res = 0;
    for (int i : cand) {
        auto cur = bfs(i, g).first;
        res = max(res, *max_element(cur.begin(), cur.end()));
    }
    return res;
}

vector<vector<int>> rand_graph(int n) {
    vector<vector<int>> g(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            if (rand() & 1) {
                g[i].push_back(j);
                g[j].push_back(i);
            }
    return g;
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 1;; i++) {
        int n = 10;
        auto g = rand_graph(n);
        int correct = get_max_dist(g);
        int got = get_max_dist_weird(g);
        if (correct != got) {
            cerr << correct << " " << got << endl;
            for (int v = 0; v < n; v++)
                for (int j : g[v])
                    if (v < j)
                        cerr << v << " " << j << endl;
        }
        assert (get_max_dist_weird(g) == get_max_dist(g));
        if (i % 1000 == 0)
            cerr << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Sure, you can't prove that the algorithm is correct this way, but it's  very likely to find a counterexample if it isn't.

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I was looking for.